# Is there any way to get attribute value in xml, inside nested tag?

Tags: xml

Is there any way to get attribute value in xml, inside nested tag?
For example:

```
<xml>
       <sometag name="Charlie">
          <nestedtag>{want to get "Charlie" here}</nestedtag>
       </sometag>
</xml>
```

Comment: Using what? XSLT? Some programming language? A terminal command? Magic?

Comment: magic is the best choice. So, I guess no way to deal with it only with xml itself...

Comment: You have a certain input and want to change that to get a certain output. Something has got to perform that change. This can be you doing it in a text editor, and XSLT engine applying an XSL transformation, an application, a script, or magic, but you're going to need *something*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need some XML-aware tool. For example, I'm maintainer of [xsh](http://metacpan.org/pod/distribution/XML-XSH2/xsh) where you can populate the value like this:

```
open file.xml ;
xcopy /xml/sometag/@name into /xml/sometag/nestedtag/text() ;
save :b ;
```